# Internet sharing between PowerMac G3 running Linux and Windows 8 computer

Tags: linux, windows, networking, network-shares, powerpc

I have a PowerMac G3 on which I have installed MintPPC Linux (a version of Debian) so I can run it as a web server. This computer has two network cards, one is in the motherboard and one is a PCI network card. The G3 is connected to the home router via CAT cable on the Motherboard network card. I also have a Windows 8 computer which is connected to the G3 via regular CAT cable connected to the PCI network card.

I was wondering, how I could configure the PowerMac so that BOTH computers can use the internet at the same time? (The Windows 8 computer would be used for all kinds of internet and the G3 would be used just as a server)

In case it matters, the Windows 8 computer has a gigabyte GA-78LMT-S2P motherboard.

Comment: What flavour of linux?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Mint PPC (a version of Debian).

Comment: I can't remember the exact steps but all you need to do is to bridge the two network cards - do you have network manager?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have bridged it, but I can only access the internet on the windows computer.